# How can I change the color of the ANT Design's Spin component?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

According to my research I can change the style of ANT components using the "style" prop (Even though that's not exactly in the docs of the [Spin component](https://ant.design/components/spin/))

Here's my attempt:

```
<Col>
  {userCompaniesLoading ? (
    <Spin style={{ color: 'white' }} />
  ) : (
    <UserOutlined
      onClick={() => {
        setDrawerVisibility(!isDrawerVisible);
      }}
    />
  )}
</Col>
```

On inspect, each dot of the Spin is a "`<i class="ant-spin-dot-item"></i>`", and the `color` property does not work. So, how can I change the color of the Spin component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also if you want to change the color of the tip you need to change this class:

> .ant-spin-text {
> color: #999;   }

Looks like before tip class was .ant-spin-tip, but that didn't work for me.

Just sharing this in case it helps someone :D

Answer (score 10):

You can set the Spin Component Color by adapting the background-color of the `ant-spin-dot-item` in your component css file.

```
.ant-spin-dot-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a [CodeSandBox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-jones-rrqh2) with a changed `index.css`.

---

Btw. a more robust and production ready way to adapt antd style is to create a [custom theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme).

Using a [customized Webpack](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-webpack) config works good in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is nice. I just wanted to add that now (antd 5.6.4 in my case) you have to add `!important` to make it work.

```
.ant-spin-dot-item {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```